# OSX WebKit javascript doesn't know alert()

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, webkit

The webkit framework allows to run Javascript in a frame. I used that with success, but now want to show error messages from JS in my host application. I know you can directly call obj-c/swift methods from JS (which I use for other purposes), but I thought it would make sense to use the alert() function from JS. For that I set my class to be the UIDelegate on the WebView class and overrode the runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage method.

Unfortunately, I cannot test this because when I use e.g. `alert("Test");` in my test script I only get the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: alert

Is `alert()` not supported in WebKit (which would be strange given the UIDelegate method) or what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.alert("Test")
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Does not work either, probably because I have no window set for the WebView (which is totally fine otherwise).